# Why is maven downloading the same artifact multiple times?

Tags: maven, nexus

I run a maven build and I see the same artifact downloaded several times. After a successful download from one repo, a download from another repo is attempted. Some downloads are (0 B at 0.0 KB/sec).

```
[INFO] Downloading: https://p-nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/Myproject-group/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://p-nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/Myproject-group/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar (5 KB at 59.8 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: https://p-nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[INFO] Downloaded: https://p-nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar (0 B at 0.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.spring.io/ext-release-local/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.spring.io/milestone/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[INFO] Downloading: http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
```

The repository configuration:

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Myproject-group</id>
        <name>Myproject-group</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>https://p-nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/Myproject-group/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: It's not really a good idea to have the `updatePolicy` of `snapshots` repositories set to `never`. This will never bring you any changes beyond the first downloaded version of a snapshot artifact. What you're doing will only make sense, if the group you're using only contains release repositories.

Comment: carlspring, this repository does not contain snapshots. I believe updatePolicy is superfluous here, I just added all settings that could influence this downloading.

Comment: Configure your nexus repository correct (single group to use) and only use a single group in your settings.xml file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force Maven to use a single repository by having it mirror all repository requests. The repository must contain all of the desired artifacts, or be able to proxy the requests to other repositories. This setting is most useful when using an internal company repository with the Maven Repository Manager to proxy external requests.

To achieve this, set mirrorOf to *.

```
<settings>
  ...
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>internal-repository</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Manager running on repo.mycompany.com</name>
      <url>http://repo.mycompany.com/proxy</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  ...
</settings>
```

more details [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html)

hope this helps.

Comment: This is probably the best way to get rid of the problem, although I don't understand why this happens in the first place.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the log information, you will see that it did not download multiple times.

```
[INFO] Downloaded: https://p-nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/Myproject-group/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar (5 KB at 59.8 KB/sec)

[INFO] Downloaded: https://p-nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar (0 B at 0.0 KB/sec)
```

As you can see, their paths are different, even if the jar files are same and at the end of the second INFO, it says `0 B at 0.0 KB/sec` that means, it was not downloaded.

Comment: Thank you, I had not noticed this and it is probably the clue to the explanation. It is still the same artifact and it was downloaded once, so why the second attempt?

Comment: While the paths are different, my belief is that maven looks at the REPO meta-data for the artifact (e.g., `aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/`) and not the URL path to determine if they are the same or different.  If the metadata is different then it considers that it is out of date (just a guess here).
Because the artifact is the same, I agree with Assen that I wonder why it would be downloaded again. One possible answer is, it downloaded the metadata found it was identical to what was in the local repo and did not need to download it *again*.

Answer (score 3):

It's not downloading it multiple times. It's not able to find it in the first repository, so it's trying the next one on your `<repositories/>` list.

Comment: But 1) the artifact is there and 2) Why does it say Downloaded for the repository which has the artifact and not for the others?

Comment: CORRECTION: This log was taken from a build run with maven 2.2.x, this may be the reason of the whole issue.

Comment: Why the downvote? At the down-voter: Please, explain.

Comment: @AssenKolov: The behaviour between Maven 2.2.x and 3.3.x has not changed in this regard.